# iOS stream audio with no extension

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I am looking to play a live audio stream within my app using AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer, however the link has no extension and so whenever I try to set it up, it fails. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Code:

```
NSString *path = @"http://audio7.radioreference.com/24705802";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
NSError *error;

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
player.volume = 1.0f;
player.numberOfLoops = -1.0f;
[player prepareToPlay];

if (player == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ Description: %@", error.localizedDescription, error.description);
}
else {
    [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSData does not constitute a stream, but static data (eg sound data that you created or data loaded from a file). You want to create an AVPlayer object with an NSURL pointing to the stream. For example:

```
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];

[player play];
```